# C# WebSite connection to a mySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, web, localhost

I want to connect my WebSite to a local database.
My connection String is the following:

```
     <connectionStrings>

<add name ="localhost"

 connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=doctorappointments" 
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
 />
```

I can connect from MySql Workbench and also from Visual Studio if I add a new connection in Server Explorer. The connection String from above is the same as the one from server Explorer.
I checked that my server is running, I also put a firewall rule for the port that it connects to.

This how I am using the connectionString:

```
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localhost"].ConnectionString))
        {

        con.Open();
        Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");

        }
```

And on the con.Open() it gives me this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in >System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred >while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was >not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is >configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: >40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

and also:

> - ServerVersion   'con.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'   string {System.InvalidOperationException}

I am new to this and I have tried everything I found online. I do not know what am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

`SqlConnection` is for Sql Server.

Make sure you have installed `MySql.Data` via nuget package and use `MySqlConnection` instead.